# Inconsistent cartesian product using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I've got the following definitions of 3 axes vectors:

```py
arena = np.array([[-0.1, 0.1], [-0.1, 0.1], [0.06, 0.14]], dtype=np.float32)
resolution = np.array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01], dtype=np.float32)

axes_size = np.array((arena[:, 1] - arena[:, 0]) / resolution).astype(np.int32)
axes = [np.linspace(*arena[i], axes_size[i], endpoint=False, dtype=np.float32)
        for i in np.arange(axes_size.shape[0])]
```

Note that `axes_size = array([20, 20,  8], dtype=int32)`.

I'm trying to vectorize & generalize the following piece of code that create the cartesian product of `axes`:

```py
points = np.zeros([*axes_size, 3])
points[:, :, :, 0] = axes[0][:, None, None]
points[:, :, :, 1] = axes[1][None, :, None]
points[:, :, :, 2] = axes[2][None, None, :]
```

Note that `points.shape = (20, 20, 8, 3)`.

I tried the following:

```py
points = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*axes), axis=-1)
points = np.array(np.meshgrid(*axes)).T.reshape(-1, 3).T.reshape(*axes_size, 3)
```

Both lines seems to fail when comparing the results using `np.testing.assert_allclose()`, and I can't seem to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `np.meshgrid` has a default setting that is not what most people would expect.

Add `indexing='ij'` to create sane behavior:

```
points = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*axes, indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
```

This will pass the `np.allclose` test.

The default of `np.meshgrid` is `indexing='xy'` which reverses the order of the first two axes. This is supposedly convenient for image data, where a 800x400 image (width 800, height 400) should be a shape (400, 800) array.

```
>>> np.meshgrid(np.arange(20), np.arange(21), np.arange(3))[0].shape
(21, 20, 3)

>>> np.meshgrid(np.arange(20), np.arange(21), np.arange(3), indexing='ij')[0].shape
(20, 21, 3)
```

If I deal with multidimensional arrays, I try to have different sizes along different axes, e.g. `(20, 21, 8, 3)` rather than `(20, 20, 8, 3)` so that I will catch this type of problem.

Comment: This is great! So the default indexing reverse the order of the axes - but only the first two apparently, am I correct? Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Yep, "convenient" for RGB images with shape `(ny, nx, 3)`. I've been bitten by the `indexing='xy'` quite a few times. Blame it on Matlab's design that inspired numpy.